# Oracle Data Provider for .net

Tags: odp.net

I would like to know whether there is a difference in functionality between ODP.net for .net 1.1 and ODP.net for .net 2.0 or higher. Are there any performance differencies?

Answer (score 0):

It depends... 8-)

The provider for .Net 2.0 support more advanced features that allow data insertion and retrieval operation to be much faster but you need to change your code to use them.

If you're willing to change your code and need the new features improvement could be very effective (for example the array parameter functionality could really speed up massive insert operation, I do not remember if it's available in the 1.1 provider but I do not think so).

As for simply using the same code in Microsoft.NET 1.1 with ODP.Net 1.1 or using with Microsoft.NET 2.0 and ODP.Net 2.0 I do not think you will see great improvements.